# Query assembly

Tags: unit-testing, reflection, powershell

I have a .NET assembly that has tens of classes and methods which are unit testing methods.
I want to generate a report with all the method marked with attribute Ignore,
do you know a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the get [Custom Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcustomattributes.aspx) method

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.Load("yourassembly.dll");
object[] attributes = ass.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IgnoreAttribute), false));
```

This method also exists on the method object, so you can iterate through all the types in your assembly and iterate through all their methods, and call the same method.

```
foreach(Type type in ass.GetTypes()) {
    foreach(MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods()) {
       method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IgnoreAttribute), true));
    }
}
```

Edit, Here is some help with the powershell syntax, although I must say, I am NOT powershell fluent. I am sure someone can do this way better than the crap I have below.

```
$types = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\dll.dll").GetTypes()
$attribute = [System.Type]::GetType("IgnoreAttribute")
foreach ($type in $types) { 
    $methods = $type.GetMethods()
    foreach ($method in $methods) { 
    if ($method .GetCustomAttributes($attribute).Length -gt 0) { 
        $method.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot 
That was helpfull, but can I do it in Powershell?
I am trying to translate the syntax above to powershell

Comment: I've updated my answer to include something which should work in powershell. I think it can be done better, but my powershell isn't up to par

Comment: I wouldn't use Write-Host in this case.  While you can see the result on the screen, you can't capture the result to a variable. Just eliminate the Write-Host and the $method.Name will automatically be output.

Comment: For stuff like this, always use [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom ... not LoadFile

Comment: @Jaykul, why does this matter? We aren't interested in loading any dependencies, we just want to know about the classes in that assembly.